# Pandas concat dataframes issue with dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have an issue with concat 2 dataframes.
Before concat both got this same column names and date formats.
But after concat dates from one of them got timestamp so I can't remove duplicates.

```
def save_csv_backup(self, new_df, unit):
    backup_file = f'{self.archives_file_path}/mutoh_{unit}.csv'
    current_data = self.get_CSV(backup_file)
    if current_data is None or current_data.empty:
        new_df.to_csv(backup_file, header='true',
                           index=False, date_format='%Y-%m-%d')
    else:
        new_df["Data"] = pd.to_datetime(
        new_df["Data"].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
        print('CURRENT_DATA')
        print(current_data)
        print('NEW_DATA')
        print(new_df)
        print('łączę')
        merged_df = pd.concat([current_data, new_df]).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
        print(merged_df)
        self.remove_CSV(backup_file)
        merged_df.to_csv(backup_file, header='true',
                                index=False, date_format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

just before concat changing date format for new_df

```
new_df["Data"] = pd.to_datetime(new_df["Data"].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

but without any better results...

RESULT:

```
CURRENT_DATA
units_BACK   |          Data    lst_date     Ink  Printed      unit
units_BACK   | 0  2021-05-01  2022-03-08  2248.0    535.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 1  2021-06-01  2022-03-08  3493.0    810.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 2  2021-07-01  2022-03-08  4229.0    958.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 3  2021-08-01  2022-03-08  5726.0   1259.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 4  2021-09-01  2022-03-08  6719.0   1515.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 5  2021-10-01  2022-03-08  7584.0   1566.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 6  2021-11-01  2022-03-08  7939.0   1903.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 7  2021-12-01  2022-03-08  7853.0   1774.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 8  2022-01-01  2022-03-08  7481.0   1795.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | NEW_DATA
units_BACK   |          Data   lst_date     Ink  Printed      unit
units_BACK   | 0  2021-05-01 2022-03-08  2248.0    535.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 1  2021-06-01 2022-03-08  3493.0    810.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 2  2021-07-01 2022-03-08  4229.0    958.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 3  2021-08-01 2022-03-08  5726.0   1259.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 4  2021-09-01 2022-03-08  6719.0   1515.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 5  2021-10-01 2022-03-08  7584.0   1566.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 6  2021-11-01 2022-03-08  7939.0   1903.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 7  2021-12-01 2022-03-08  7853.0   1774.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 8  2022-01-01 2022-03-08  7481.0   1795.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 9  2022-02-01 2022-03-08  1645.0    394.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 10 2022-03-01 2022-03-08    14.0      3.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | łączę
units_BACK   |                    Data             lst_date     Ink  Printed      unit
units_BACK   | 0            2021-05-01           2022-03-08  2248.0    535.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 1            2021-06-01           2022-03-08  3493.0    810.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 2            2021-07-01           2022-03-08  4229.0    958.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 3            2021-08-01           2022-03-08  5726.0   1259.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 4            2021-09-01           2022-03-08  6719.0   1515.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 5            2021-10-01           2022-03-08  7584.0   1566.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 6            2021-11-01           2022-03-08  7939.0   1903.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 7            2021-12-01           2022-03-08  7853.0   1774.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 8            2022-01-01           2022-03-08  7481.0   1795.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 9   2021-05-01 00:00:00  2022-03-08 00:00:00  2248.0    535.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 10  2021-06-01 00:00:00  2022-03-08 00:00:00  3493.0    810.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 11  2021-07-01 00:00:00  2022-03-08 00:00:00  4229.0    958.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 12  2021-08-01 00:00:00  2022-03-08 00:00:00  5726.0   1259.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 13  2021-09-01 00:00:00  2022-03-08 00:00:00  6719.0   1515.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 14  2021-10-01 00:00:00  2022-03-08 00:00:00  7584.0   1566.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 15  2021-11-01 00:00:00  2022-03-08 00:00:00  7939.0   1903.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 16  2021-12-01 00:00:00  2022-03-08 00:00:00  7853.0   1774.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 17  2022-01-01 00:00:00  2022-03-08 00:00:00  7481.0   1795.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 18  2022-02-01 00:00:00  2022-03-08 00:00:00  1645.0    394.0  Mutoh 28
units_BACK   | 19  2022-03-01 00:00:00  2022-03-08 00:00:00    14.0      3.0  Mutoh 28
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of `print(merge_df.head().to_dict())`, please?

Comment: sure: 

`{'Data': {0: '2021-05-01', 1: '2021-06-01', 2: '2021-07-01', 3: '2021-08-01', 4: '2021-09-01'}, 'lst_date': {0: '2022-03-08', 1: '2022-03-08', 2: '2022-03-08', 3: '2022-03-08', 4: '2022-03-08'}, 'Ink': {0: 2248.0, 1: 3493.0, 2: 4229.0, 3: 5726.0, 4: 6719.0}, 'Printed': {0: 535.0, 1: 810.0, 2: 958.0, 3: 1259.0, 4: 1515.0}, 'unit': {0: 'Mutoh 28', 1: 'Mutoh 28', 2: 'Mutoh 28', 3: 'Mutoh 28', 4: 'Mutoh 28'}}`

Comment: I don't understand why after converting this merged_df to dict he get me only 5 elements not 19...

Comment: `head` extract only the first 5 elements by default

Comment: Why do you need to convert `Data` column as `DatetimeIndex`?

Comment: this data are from log files from printing units. I need to convert date earlier because I need it. I left that data format to not convert data over and over again.

Comment: What are the dtypes of `current_data`: `print(current_data.dtypes)`

Comment: @Corralien you right.. both df have different types for dates:
CURRENT `Data         object`
NEW_DATA `Data        datetime64[ns]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to modify your `get_CSV` method:

```
def get_CSV(self, backup_file):
   df = pd.read_csv(..., parse_dates=['Data'])
   return df
```

However you also need to subset your columns for identifying duplicates:

```
merged_df = (pd.concat([current_data, new_df])
               .drop_duplicates('Data', keep='last')
               .sort_values('Data', ignore_index=True))
```

Output:

```
>>> merged_df
          Data    lst_date     Ink  Printed      unit
0   2021-05-01  2022-03-08  2248.0    535.0  Mutoh 28
1   2021-06-01  2022-03-08  3493.0    810.0  Mutoh 28
2   2021-07-01  2022-03-08  4229.0    958.0  Mutoh 28
3   2021-08-01  2022-03-08  5726.0   1259.0  Mutoh 28
4   2021-09-01  2022-03-08  6719.0   1515.0  Mutoh 28
5   2021-10-01  2022-03-08  7584.0   1566.0  Mutoh 28
6   2021-11-01  2022-03-08  7939.0   1903.0  Mutoh 28
7   2021-12-01  2022-03-08  7853.0   1774.0  Mutoh 28
8   2022-01-01  2022-03-08  7481.0   1795.0  Mutoh 28
9   2022-02-01  2022-03-08  1645.0    394.0  Mutoh 28
10  2022-03-01  2022-03-08    14.0      3.0  Mutoh 28
```

Comment: I succeeded to reproduce your problem. You have to modify your method `get_CSV` to convert `Data` column as `datetime64` using `parse_dates` parameter of `pd.read_csv`. Can you check it please?

Comment: Yeap, that was it! 
Thanks bro! parse_dates get me write date format but also `drop_duplicates('Data', keep='last')` was needed